# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js/vue, the project starter template was already created, and I have alot of error message along with Maximun call stack size exceeded... I am not sure how to chase down this error message, or exactly where it is steming from.... Does any one have a method of how I can find out where these issues are coming from?

error messages:

```
WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformRequest                                                      14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformResponse                                                     14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function httpAdapter                                                           14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function validateStatus                                                        14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs ClientRequest                                                14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function                                                                       14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformRequest                                                      14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformResponse                                                     14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function httpAdapter                                                           14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function validateStatus                                                        14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs ClientRequest                                                14:52:50


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function                                                                       14:52:50
```

AND

[image]

Comment: What does "the project starter template was already created" mean? Which project? Created how?

Comment: Try to reinstall the nuxt

Comment: so the project base template was already created by someone else. It included all base files I would need. The project usees nuxt.js, vuex... headlesswordpress cms... it was all set up by another person...

Comment: I have the exact same issue, reported here https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c10415

Answer (score 1):

in my case, it was because i uase **setInterval()** inside the nuxt method ***async fetch()*** ;
i have solved it by moving **setInterval()** to the new method inside the method object and call it by watching some data changes